# how to fix uwsgi services failure to start in centos 7

Tags: django, web-services, nginx, uwsgi

```
uwsgi.service - uWSGI Emperor service

   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)

   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Sun 2016-05-22 05:46:09 EDT; 5min ago

  Process: 6371 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/bash -c mkdir -p /run/uwsgi; chown user:nginx /run/uwsgi (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 22 05:46:09 apxyws systemd[1]: Failed to start uWSGI Emperor service.

May 22 05:46:09 apxyws systemd[1]: Unit uwsgi.service entered failed state.

May 22 05:46:09 apxyws systemd[1]: uwsgi.service failed.

May 22 05:46:09 apxyws systemd[1]: uwsgi.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.

May 22 05:46:09 apxyws systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for uwsgi.service

May 22 05:46:09 apxyws systemd[1]: Failed to start uWSGI Emperor service.

May 22 05:46:09 apxyws systemd[1]: Unit uwsgi.service entered failed state.

May 22 05:46:09 apxyws systemd[1]: uwsgi.service failed.
```

Does anybody know how to fix something like this, i am still newbie for setup things like this, been searching the answer but nothing similiar to me.

i just started using django and it worked using:

```
uwsgi --http :8080 --home /root/Env/apxweb --chdir /root/apxweb -w apxweb.wsgi
```

but when i started using it with nginx, 
uwsgi service failure to start.

notes: nginx service worked.

Comment: Looks like it's failing on the ExecStartPre line in your uwsgi.service file. Do the user and group from the chown command exist?

Comment: yea @LukeDixon you are correct, and the problem is within user, uwsgi worked again but badgateway 502, maybe another mistake i do before, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Luke Dixon,

Yes the problem is within user,
I update the file like this:

```js
/usr/bin/bash -c mkdir -p /run/uwsgi; chown root:nginx /run/uwsgi
```

uwsgi worked again,
i dont know if this is the correct way to fix uwsgi,
but anyway thank you very much.